# What is a "Special" price in league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just fell on this while doing arams.

[image]

So what is it? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The item is marked as Special because it's unpurchasable; you can only acquire it by performing some action with another item.

Right now, the only Special price items are Muramana and Seraph's Embrace. They replace Manamune and Archangel's Staff, respectively, when you fully stack the Mana Charge unique passive.